# New command to number paragraphs (related counter)

Tags: macros, sectioning

I use KOMA class (scrbook). My goal : I try to create a command (let's say \verset) that will display a number, each time indented. A title should be put as argument An example :

> \verset \lipsum
>
> \verset{Description} \lipsum

will display (Microsoft Word example)

[image]

The snag is that I don't want those numbers at the beginning of every paragraph, but only when I call \verset.

Another difficulty is that I want my bibliography and index not to send to the page number of the occurence, but to the number of the verset.

I am really a dumb with renewcommand and setcounter stuff. I would appreciate much a bit of help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The requirement is easy to fulfill:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\verset}[1][]{\stepcounter{verset}%
  \textbf{\theverset.
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else
      #1
    \fi
  }%
}
\newcounter{verset}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\verset \lipsum[2]

\verset[Description] \lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just need one index, the following will use the verset number instead of the page number

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd{\@wrindex}{\thepage}{\theverset}{}{}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\verset}[1][]{\stepcounter{verset}%
  \textbf{\theverset.
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else
      #1
    \fi
  }%
}
\newcounter{verset}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\verset \lipsum[2]\index{horse}

\verset[Description] \lipsum[3]\index{elephant}

\lipsum[4]\index{lion}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A version that adds a period to the verset title, if it doesn't already ends with punctuation. The `amsthm` package has an `\@addpunct` feature that comes handy for the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \@addpunct
\makeindex
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd{\@wrindex}{\thepage}{\theverset}{}{}}

\newcommand{\verset}[1][]{\stepcounter{verset}%
  \textbf{\theverset.%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else
      \space #1\@addpunct{.}%
    \fi
  }%
  \hspace{0.5em}\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{verset}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\verset \lipsum[2]\index{horse}

\verset[Description] \lipsum[3]\index{elephant}

\verset[Period.] Short

\verset[Question?] Short

\lipsum[4]\index{lion}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The `\@addpunct{.}` macro checks the current space factor, which is larger after punctuation (even if `\frenchspacing` is in force), and conditionally adds a period.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer !

About index (not bilbio, my bad) : the number related to a word links to the page where the word occurs. I want the number to refer to the number of the verset of the paragraph where the word occurs.

An example : I use \index{horse} somewhere in my document. The targeted word will be at the page 10 in the output, but after the verset number 5. Thus I want the index to display "Horse... 5".

Comment: @Gaspalet I added the code you needed.

Comment: Awesome, you're amazing. Merci !

Comment: I'm trying to change the code a bit. Any idea why the \autodot command does not work ? I unsuccessfully tried this :
`\newcommand{\verset}[1][]{\stepcounter{verset}%
  \textbf{\theverset.
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else
      #1
    \fi
  }%
  \autodot\hspace{0.5em}
}`

Comment: @Gaspalet Where's `\autodot` coming from? And what's the expected output?

Comment: From me ! I'm trying to automatically add a dot if the title of the verset has no one (the \autodot command), and add some space before the text begins (the \hspace command). Bad luck it's not working...

Comment: @Gaspalet You find the new version on line. :)

Comment: I'm still lagging begind with my code... Would you have a quick code to adapt the crossing reference \pageref : I don't want it to return the page where the label is but the number of the "verset". Any help ?

Comment: @Gaspalet `\pageref` always points to the top of the page where the target is.

Comment: Ok. So I have to create a new command (like \versetref{example}) that displays the number of the verset that contains \label{example} (or another trigger command) ?

Comment: @Gaspalet Change `\stepcounter` into `\refstepcounter` and use `\ref`.